# Getting "Bad request" response in browser, but 'OK' from Postman, even though I'm using same request body

Tags: javascript, rest, browser, postman, response

This is request in browser

[image]

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "enrichmentExpression":"!(:DOCUMENT_NAME.equals(\"SOF\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTVB1\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTVBC\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTMC1\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTVIN\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTMCN\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTMHP\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTVP1\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTVPB\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTVCI\"))",
      "variables":{
         "RUN_ID":"",
         "BARCODE":"",
         "ENV_NUM":"",
         "PATH_PS":"",
         "ORDER_BY":"",
         "PATH_RAW":"",
         "SORT_COL":"",
         "COMB_TYPE":"",
         "FILE_NAME":"",
         "INDEX_DOC":"",
         "PAGE_TYPE":"",
         "SUB_BRAND":"",
         "CONTRACT_ID":"",
         "DOCUMENT_ID":"",
         "INSTANCE_ID":"",
         "PAGE_NUMBER":"",
         "PATH_SIGNED":"",
         "PRINT_STYLE":"",
         "SOURCE_PATH":"",
         "INDEX_ADRESS":"",
         "PATH_ARCHIVE":"",
         "BARCODE_VALUE":"",
         "CHANNEL_LABEL":"",
         "DOCUMENT_NAME":"",
         "ENVELOPE_SIZE":"",
         "MAX_WAIT_DATE":"",
         "COMBINATION_ID":"",
         "DOCUMENT_LABEL":"",
         "FILE_EXTENSION":"",
         "ID_BF_DOCUMENT":"",
         "RUN_START_DATE":"",
         "STANDING_ORDER":"",
         "ADDRESS_BARCODE":"",
         "ENVELOPE_ACTION":"",
         "ENVELOPE_NUMBER":"",
         "FLAG_FILE_SPLIT":"",
         "COMBINATION_TYPE":"",
         "ENVELOPE_MESSAGE":"",
         "LAST_IN_ENVELOPE":"",
         "DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM":"",
         "FILE_SUBDIRECTORY":"",
         "FIRST_IN_ENVELOPE":"",
         "PAGE_COUNT_DUPLEX":"",
         "PAGE_PAYMENT_SLIP":"",
         "D_DOCUMENT_REF_NBR":"",
         "FULL_DOCUMENT_NAME":"",
         "PAGE_COUNT_SIMPLEX":"",
         "PAGE_NUMBER_IN_PDF":"",
         "SHEET_COUNT_DUPLEX":"",
         "SN_ENVELOPE_NUMBER":"",
         "COMBINATION_ID_NEXT":"",
         "COMBINATION_ID_PREV":"",
         "CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID":"",
         "FLAG_ENVELOPE_SPLIT":"",
         "ID_BF_DOCUMENT_NEXT":"",
         "ID_BF_DOCUMENT_PREV":"",
         "SHEET_COUNT_SIMPLEX":"",
         "CURR_PAGE_NUM_IN_DOC":"",
         "CURR_PAGE_NUM_IN_ENV":"",
         "DOC_PAGE_NUM_IN_BULK":"",
         "ENVELOPE_NUM_IN_BULK":"",
         "DOCUMENT_PAYMENT_SLIP":"",
         "BULK_DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM":"",
         "BULK_PHISICAL_PAGE_NUM":"",
         "COMB_DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_DOC":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_ENV":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_COMB":"",
         "CUSTOMER_ENVELOPE_NUMBER":"",
         "ROTATE_CLOCKWISE_DEGREES":"",
         "FIRST_PAGE_NUM_IN_BULK_DOC":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_JOB":"",
         "ENVELOPE_STUFFER_BARCODE_VAL":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_DOCUMENT_ID":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_COMBINATION_ID":"",
         "PATH":"",
         "BRAND":"",
         "JOB_ID":""
      }
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "enrichmentExpression":"",
      "variables":{
         "RUN_ID":"",
         "BARCODE":"",
         "ENV_NUM":"",
         "PATH_PS":"",
         "ORDER_BY":"",
         "PATH_RAW":"",
         "SORT_COL":"",
         "COMB_TYPE":"",
         "FILE_NAME":"",
         "INDEX_DOC":"",
         "PAGE_TYPE":"",
         "SUB_BRAND":"",
         "CONTRACT_ID":"",
         "DOCUMENT_ID":"",
         "INSTANCE_ID":"",
         "PAGE_NUMBER":"",
         "PATH_SIGNED":"",
         "PRINT_STYLE":"",
         "SOURCE_PATH":"",
         "INDEX_ADRESS":"",
         "PATH_ARCHIVE":"",
         "BARCODE_VALUE":"",
         "CHANNEL_LABEL":"",
         "DOCUMENT_NAME":"",
         "ENVELOPE_SIZE":"",
         "MAX_WAIT_DATE":"",
         "COMBINATION_ID":"",
         "DOCUMENT_LABEL":"",
         "FILE_EXTENSION":"",
         "ID_BF_DOCUMENT":"",
         "RUN_START_DATE":"",
         "STANDING_ORDER":"",
         "ADDRESS_BARCODE":"",
         "ENVELOPE_ACTION":"",
         "ENVELOPE_NUMBER":"",
         "FLAG_FILE_SPLIT":"",
         "COMBINATION_TYPE":"",
         "ENVELOPE_MESSAGE":"",
         "LAST_IN_ENVELOPE":"",
         "DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM":"",
         "FILE_SUBDIRECTORY":"",
         "FIRST_IN_ENVELOPE":"",
         "PAGE_COUNT_DUPLEX":"",
         "PAGE_PAYMENT_SLIP":"",
         "D_DOCUMENT_REF_NBR":"",
         "FULL_DOCUMENT_NAME":"",
         "PAGE_COUNT_SIMPLEX":"",
         "PAGE_NUMBER_IN_PDF":"",
         "SHEET_COUNT_DUPLEX":"",
         "SN_ENVELOPE_NUMBER":"",
         "COMBINATION_ID_NEXT":"",
         "COMBINATION_ID_PREV":"",
         "CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID":"",
         "FLAG_ENVELOPE_SPLIT":"",
         "ID_BF_DOCUMENT_NEXT":"",
         "ID_BF_DOCUMENT_PREV":"",
         "SHEET_COUNT_SIMPLEX":"",
         "CURR_PAGE_NUM_IN_DOC":"",
         "CURR_PAGE_NUM_IN_ENV":"",
         "DOC_PAGE_NUM_IN_BULK":"",
         "ENVELOPE_NUM_IN_BULK":"",
         "DOCUMENT_PAYMENT_SLIP":"",
         "BULK_DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM":"",
         "BULK_PHISICAL_PAGE_NUM":"",
         "COMB_DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_DOC":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_ENV":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_COMB":"",
         "CUSTOMER_ENVELOPE_NUMBER":"",
         "ROTATE_CLOCKWISE_DEGREES":"",
         "FIRST_PAGE_NUM_IN_BULK_DOC":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_JOB":"",
         "ENVELOPE_STUFFER_BARCODE_VAL":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_DOCUMENT_ID":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_COMBINATION_ID":"",
         "PATH":"",
         "BRAND":"",
         "JOB_ID":""
      }
   },
   {
      "id":"3",
      "enrichmentExpression":"",
      "variables":{
         "RUN_ID":"",
         "BARCODE":"",
         "ENV_NUM":"",
         "PATH_PS":"",
         "ORDER_BY":"",
         "PATH_RAW":"",
         "SORT_COL":"",
         "COMB_TYPE":"",
         "FILE_NAME":"",
         "INDEX_DOC":"",
         "PAGE_TYPE":"",
         "SUB_BRAND":"",
         "CONTRACT_ID":"",
         "DOCUMENT_ID":"",
         "INSTANCE_ID":"",
         "PAGE_NUMBER":"",
         "PATH_SIGNED":"",
         "PRINT_STYLE":"",
         "SOURCE_PATH":"",
         "INDEX_ADRESS":"",
         "PATH_ARCHIVE":"",
         "BARCODE_VALUE":"",
         "CHANNEL_LABEL":"",
         "DOCUMENT_NAME":"",
         "ENVELOPE_SIZE":"",
         "MAX_WAIT_DATE":"",
         "COMBINATION_ID":"",
         "DOCUMENT_LABEL":"",
         "FILE_EXTENSION":"",
         "ID_BF_DOCUMENT":"",
         "RUN_START_DATE":"",
         "STANDING_ORDER":"",
         "ADDRESS_BARCODE":"",
         "ENVELOPE_ACTION":"",
         "ENVELOPE_NUMBER":"",
         "FLAG_FILE_SPLIT":"",
         "COMBINATION_TYPE":"",
         "ENVELOPE_MESSAGE":"",
         "LAST_IN_ENVELOPE":"",
         "DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM":"",
         "FILE_SUBDIRECTORY":"",
         "FIRST_IN_ENVELOPE":"",
         "PAGE_COUNT_DUPLEX":"",
         "PAGE_PAYMENT_SLIP":"",
         "D_DOCUMENT_REF_NBR":"",
         "FULL_DOCUMENT_NAME":"",
         "PAGE_COUNT_SIMPLEX":"",
         "PAGE_NUMBER_IN_PDF":"",
         "SHEET_COUNT_DUPLEX":"",
         "SN_ENVELOPE_NUMBER":"",
         "COMBINATION_ID_NEXT":"",
         "COMBINATION_ID_PREV":"",
         "CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID":"",
         "FLAG_ENVELOPE_SPLIT":"",
         "ID_BF_DOCUMENT_NEXT":"",
         "ID_BF_DOCUMENT_PREV":"",
         "SHEET_COUNT_SIMPLEX":"",
         "CURR_PAGE_NUM_IN_DOC":"",
         "CURR_PAGE_NUM_IN_ENV":"",
         "DOC_PAGE_NUM_IN_BULK":"",
         "ENVELOPE_NUM_IN_BULK":"",
         "DOCUMENT_PAYMENT_SLIP":"",
         "BULK_DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM":"",
         "BULK_PHISICAL_PAGE_NUM":"",
         "COMB_DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_DOC":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_ENV":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_COMB":"",
         "CUSTOMER_ENVELOPE_NUMBER":"",
         "ROTATE_CLOCKWISE_DEGREES":"",
         "FIRST_PAGE_NUM_IN_BULK_DOC":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_JOB":"",
         "ENVELOPE_STUFFER_BARCODE_VAL":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_DOCUMENT_ID":"",
         "TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_COMBINATION_ID":"",
         "PATH":"",
         "BRAND":"",
         "JOB_ID":""
      }
   }
]
```

This is response

```
{
   "code":"400 BAD_REQUEST",
   "message":"BAD_REQUEST",
   "timestamp":"2023-09-20 06:28:48.958",
   "retryable":false,
   "severity":"ERROR",
   "details":{
      "Message":"Request body is invalid Šifra greške: 48687",
      "SessionId":null,
      "MessageName":"Bad Request"
   }
}
```

But when I do the same in Postman I'm getting 'OK' with a valid response. So I literally copy and paste request from Firefox (Raw version of JSON) to Postman and it's fine.

[image]

Request from Postman

```
[{"id":"1","enrichmentExpression":"!(:DOCUMENT_NAME.equals(\"SOF\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTVB1\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTVBC\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTMC1\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTVIN\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTMCN\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTMHP\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTVP1\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTVPB\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTVCI\"))","variables":{"JOB_ID":"","RUN_ID":"","BARCODE":"","ENV_NUM":"","PATH_PS":"","ORDER_BY":"","PATH_RAW":"","SORT_COL":"","COMB_TYPE":"","FILE_NAME":"","INDEX_DOC":"","PAGE_TYPE":"","SUB_BRAND":"","CONTRACT_ID":"","DOCUMENT_ID":"","INSTANCE_ID":"","PAGE_NUMBER":"","PATH_SIGNED":"","PRINT_STYLE":"","SOURCE_PATH":"","INDEX_ADRESS":"","PATH_ARCHIVE":"","BARCODE_VALUE":"","CHANNEL_LABEL":"","DOCUMENT_NAME":"","ENVELOPE_SIZE":"","MAX_WAIT_DATE":"","COMBINATION_ID":"","DOCUMENT_LABEL":"","FILE_EXTENSION":"","ID_BF_DOCUMENT":"","RUN_START_DATE":"","STANDING_ORDER":"","ADDRESS_BARCODE":"","ENVELOPE_ACTION":"","ENVELOPE_NUMBER":"","FLAG_FILE_SPLIT":"","COMBINATION_TYPE":"","ENVELOPE_MESSAGE":"","LAST_IN_ENVELOPE":"","DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM":"","FILE_SUBDIRECTORY":"","FIRST_IN_ENVELOPE":"","PAGE_COUNT_DUPLEX":"","PAGE_PAYMENT_SLIP":"","D_DOCUMENT_REF_NBR":"","FULL_DOCUMENT_NAME":"","PAGE_COUNT_SIMPLEX":"","PAGE_NUMBER_IN_PDF":"","SHEET_COUNT_DUPLEX":"","SN_ENVELOPE_NUMBER":"","COMBINATION_ID_NEXT":"","COMBINATION_ID_PREV":"","CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID":"","FLAG_ENVELOPE_SPLIT":"","ID_BF_DOCUMENT_NEXT":"","ID_BF_DOCUMENT_PREV":"","SHEET_COUNT_SIMPLEX":"","CURR_PAGE_NUM_IN_DOC":"","CURR_PAGE_NUM_IN_ENV":"","DOC_PAGE_NUM_IN_BULK":"","ENVELOPE_NUM_IN_BULK":"","DOCUMENT_PAYMENT_SLIP":"","BULK_DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM":"","BULK_PHISICAL_PAGE_NUM":"","COMB_DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_DOC":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_ENV":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_COMB":"","CUSTOMER_ENVELOPE_NUMBER":"","ROTATE_CLOCKWISE_DEGREES":"","FIRST_PAGE_NUM_IN_BULK_DOC":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_JOB":"","ENVELOPE_STUFFER_BARCODE_VAL":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_DOCUMENT_ID":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_COMBINATION_ID":"","PATH":"","BRAND":""}},{"id":"2","enrichmentExpression":"","variables":{"JOB_ID":"","RUN_ID":"","BARCODE":"","ENV_NUM":"","PATH_PS":"","ORDER_BY":"","PATH_RAW":"","SORT_COL":"","COMB_TYPE":"","FILE_NAME":"","INDEX_DOC":"","PAGE_TYPE":"","SUB_BRAND":"","CONTRACT_ID":"","DOCUMENT_ID":"","INSTANCE_ID":"","PAGE_NUMBER":"","PATH_SIGNED":"","PRINT_STYLE":"","SOURCE_PATH":"","INDEX_ADRESS":"","PATH_ARCHIVE":"","BARCODE_VALUE":"","CHANNEL_LABEL":"","DOCUMENT_NAME":"","ENVELOPE_SIZE":"","MAX_WAIT_DATE":"","COMBINATION_ID":"","DOCUMENT_LABEL":"","FILE_EXTENSION":"","ID_BF_DOCUMENT":"","RUN_START_DATE":"","STANDING_ORDER":"","ADDRESS_BARCODE":"","ENVELOPE_ACTION":"","ENVELOPE_NUMBER":"","FLAG_FILE_SPLIT":"","COMBINATION_TYPE":"","ENVELOPE_MESSAGE":"","LAST_IN_ENVELOPE":"","DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM":"","FILE_SUBDIRECTORY":"","FIRST_IN_ENVELOPE":"","PAGE_COUNT_DUPLEX":"","PAGE_PAYMENT_SLIP":"","D_DOCUMENT_REF_NBR":"","FULL_DOCUMENT_NAME":"","PAGE_COUNT_SIMPLEX":"","PAGE_NUMBER_IN_PDF":"","SHEET_COUNT_DUPLEX":"","SN_ENVELOPE_NUMBER":"","COMBINATION_ID_NEXT":"","COMBINATION_ID_PREV":"","CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID":"","FLAG_ENVELOPE_SPLIT":"","ID_BF_DOCUMENT_NEXT":"","ID_BF_DOCUMENT_PREV":"","SHEET_COUNT_SIMPLEX":"","CURR_PAGE_NUM_IN_DOC":"","CURR_PAGE_NUM_IN_ENV":"","DOC_PAGE_NUM_IN_BULK":"","ENVELOPE_NUM_IN_BULK":"","DOCUMENT_PAYMENT_SLIP":"","BULK_DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM":"","BULK_PHISICAL_PAGE_NUM":"","COMB_DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_DOC":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_ENV":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_COMB":"","CUSTOMER_ENVELOPE_NUMBER":"","ROTATE_CLOCKWISE_DEGREES":"","FIRST_PAGE_NUM_IN_BULK_DOC":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_JOB":"","ENVELOPE_STUFFER_BARCODE_VAL":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_DOCUMENT_ID":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_COMBINATION_ID":"","PATH":"","BRAND":""}},{"id":"3","enrichmentExpression":"","variables":{"JOB_ID":"","RUN_ID":"","BARCODE":"","ENV_NUM":"","PATH_PS":"","ORDER_BY":"","PATH_RAW":"","SORT_COL":"","COMB_TYPE":"","FILE_NAME":"","INDEX_DOC":"","PAGE_TYPE":"","SUB_BRAND":"","CONTRACT_ID":"","DOCUMENT_ID":"","INSTANCE_ID":"","PAGE_NUMBER":"","PATH_SIGNED":"","PRINT_STYLE":"","SOURCE_PATH":"","INDEX_ADRESS":"","PATH_ARCHIVE":"","BARCODE_VALUE":"","CHANNEL_LABEL":"","DOCUMENT_NAME":"","ENVELOPE_SIZE":"","MAX_WAIT_DATE":"","COMBINATION_ID":"","DOCUMENT_LABEL":"","FILE_EXTENSION":"","ID_BF_DOCUMENT":"","RUN_START_DATE":"","STANDING_ORDER":"","ADDRESS_BARCODE":"","ENVELOPE_ACTION":"","ENVELOPE_NUMBER":"","FLAG_FILE_SPLIT":"","COMBINATION_TYPE":"","ENVELOPE_MESSAGE":"","LAST_IN_ENVELOPE":"","DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM":"","FILE_SUBDIRECTORY":"","FIRST_IN_ENVELOPE":"","PAGE_COUNT_DUPLEX":"","PAGE_PAYMENT_SLIP":"","D_DOCUMENT_REF_NBR":"","FULL_DOCUMENT_NAME":"","PAGE_COUNT_SIMPLEX":"","PAGE_NUMBER_IN_PDF":"","SHEET_COUNT_DUPLEX":"","SN_ENVELOPE_NUMBER":"","COMBINATION_ID_NEXT":"","COMBINATION_ID_PREV":"","CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID":"","FLAG_ENVELOPE_SPLIT":"","ID_BF_DOCUMENT_NEXT":"","ID_BF_DOCUMENT_PREV":"","SHEET_COUNT_SIMPLEX":"","CURR_PAGE_NUM_IN_DOC":"","CURR_PAGE_NUM_IN_ENV":"","DOC_PAGE_NUM_IN_BULK":"","ENVELOPE_NUM_IN_BULK":"","DOCUMENT_PAYMENT_SLIP":"","BULK_DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM":"","BULK_PHISICAL_PAGE_NUM":"","COMB_DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_DOC":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_ENV":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_COMB":"","CUSTOMER_ENVELOPE_NUMBER":"","ROTATE_CLOCKWISE_DEGREES":"","FIRST_PAGE_NUM_IN_BULK_DOC":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_JOB":"","ENVELOPE_STUFFER_BARCODE_VAL":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_DOCUMENT_ID":"","TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_COMBINATION_ID":"","PATH":"","BRAND":""}}]
```

Response in Postman

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "status": "OK",
    "meta": {
        "responseType": "HashMap",
        "responseTypeFull": "java.util.HashMap"
    },
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "isValid": "true"
        },
        "2": {
            "isValid": "false",
            "error": "ParseException: Encountered \" \"}\" \"} \"\" at line 1, column 3.\nWas expecting one of:\n    \"{\" ...\n    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...\n    <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...\n    <STRING_LITERAL> ...\n    \"true\" ...\n    \"false\" ...\n    \"null\" ...\n    \"(\" ...\n    \"[\" ...\n    \"!\" ...\n    \"not\" ...\n    \"empty\" ...\n    \"-\" ...\n    <IDENTIFIER> ...\n    <IDENTIFIER> ...\n    \"(\" ...\n    "
        },
        "3": {
            "isValid": "false",
            "error": "ParseException: Encountered \" \"}\" \"} \"\" at line 1, column 3.\nWas expecting one of:\n    \"{\" ...\n    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...\n    <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...\n    <STRING_LITERAL> ...\n    \"true\" ...\n    \"false\" ...\n    \"null\" ...\n    \"(\" ...\n    \"[\" ...\n    \"!\" ...\n    \"not\" ...\n    \"empty\" ...\n    \"-\" ...\n    <IDENTIFIER> ...\n    <IDENTIFIER> ...\n    \"(\" ...\n    "
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code that creates that request

```
var finalJsonArray = [];
var idCounter = 1; 

for (let expr of allExpressions) {
    finalJsonArray.push({
        id: String(idCounter), 
        enrichmentExpression: expr,
        variables: allVariables
    });
    idCounter++;
}

var finalJsonString = JSON.stringify(finalJsonArray);
```

And this is what console.log(finalJsonString); returns

```
"[{\"id\":\"1\",\"enrichmentExpression\":\"!(:DOCUMENT_NAME.equals(\"SOF\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTVB1\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTVBC\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTMC1\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTVIN\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTMCN\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTMHP\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTVP1\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTVPB\")) && !(:DOCUMENT_LABEL.equals(\"OOUTVCI\"))\",\"variables\":{\"JOB_ID\":\"\",\"RUN_ID\":\"\",\"BARCODE\":\"\",\"ENV_NUM\":\"\",\"PATH_PS\":\"\",\"ORDER_BY\":\"\",\"PATH_RAW\":\"\",\"SORT_COL\":\"\",\"COMB_TYPE\":\"\",\"FILE_NAME\":\"\",\"INDEX_DOC\":\"\",\"PAGE_TYPE\":\"\",\"SUB_BRAND\":\"\",\"CONTRACT_ID\":\"\",\"DOCUMENT_ID\":\"\",\"INSTANCE_ID\":\"\",\"PAGE_NUMBER\":\"\",\"PATH_SIGNED\":\"\",\"PRINT_STYLE\":\"\",\"SOURCE_PATH\":\"\",\"INDEX_ADRESS\":\"\",\"PATH_ARCHIVE\":\"\",\"BARCODE_VALUE\":\"\",\"CHANNEL_LABEL\":\"\",\"DOCUMENT_NAME\":\"\",\"ENVELOPE_SIZE\":\"\",\"MAX_WAIT_DATE\":\"\",\"COMBINATION_ID\":\"\",\"DOCUMENT_LABEL\":\"\",\"FILE_EXTENSION\":\"\",\"ID_BF_DOCUMENT\":\"\",\"RUN_START_DATE\":\"\",\"STANDING_ORDER\":\"\",\"ADDRESS_BARCODE\":\"\",\"ENVELOPE_ACTION\":\"\",\"ENVELOPE_NUMBER\":\"\",\"FLAG_FILE_SPLIT\":\"\",\"COMBINATION_TYPE\":\"\",\"ENVELOPE_MESSAGE\":\"\",\"LAST_IN_ENVELOPE\":\"\",\"DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM\":\"\",\"FILE_SUBDIRECTORY\":\"\",\"FIRST_IN_ENVELOPE\":\"\",\"PAGE_COUNT_DUPLEX\":\"\",\"PAGE_PAYMENT_SLIP\":\"\",\"D_DOCUMENT_REF_NBR\":\"\",\"FULL_DOCUMENT_NAME\":\"\",\"PAGE_COUNT_SIMPLEX\":\"\",\"PAGE_NUMBER_IN_PDF\":\"\",\"SHEET_COUNT_DUPLEX\":\"\",\"SN_ENVELOPE_NUMBER\":\"\",\"COMBINATION_ID_NEXT\":\"\",\"COMBINATION_ID_PREV\":\"\",\"CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID\":\"\",\"FLAG_ENVELOPE_SPLIT\":\"\",\"ID_BF_DOCUMENT_NEXT\":\"\",\"ID_BF_DOCUMENT_PREV\":\"\",\"SHEET_COUNT_SIMPLEX\":\"\",\"CURR_PAGE_NUM_IN_DOC\":\"\",\"CURR_PAGE_NUM_IN_ENV\":\"\",\"DOC_PAGE_NUM_IN_BULK\":\"\",\"ENVELOPE_NUM_IN_BULK\":\"\",\"DOCUMENT_PAYMENT_SLIP\":\"\",\"BULK_DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM\":\"\",\"BULK_PHISICAL_PAGE_NUM\":\"\",\"COMB_DOCUMENT_PAGE_NUM\":\"\",\"TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_DOC\":\"\",\"TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_ENV\":\"\",\"TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF\":\"\",\"TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_COMB\":\"\",\"CUSTOMER_ENVELOPE_NUMBER\":\"\",\"ROTATE_CLOCKWISE_DEGREES\":\"\",\"FIRST_PAGE_NUM_IN_BULK_DOC\":\"\",\"TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_JOB\":\"\",\"ENVELOPE_STUFFER_BARCODE_VAL\":\"\",\"TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_DOCUMENT_ID\":\"\",\"PATH\":\"\",\"BRAND\":\"\",\"TOTAL_PAGES_NUM_IN_PDF_COMBINATION_ID\":\"\"}}]"
```

Comment: How are you doing the actual request (the one which fails) using the JSON?

Comment: We have intern framework that does it via db

Like this https://i.ibb.co/n02fY53/image.png

Comment: In the image it shows, that the body is formatted as x-www-form-urlencoded, that's what the server expects to see, but it gets JSON instead. You've to consult the documentation of this secret framework to find out how JSON should be sent. Postman automatically formats the body correctly before sending.

Comment: So I should change from application/json to application/x-www-form-urlencoded ?
and make changes in JS so that it doesn't make JSON but x-www-form-urlencoded ?

Comment: It's hard to say anything further without knowing the details of how the used framework works with JSON bodies.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how did you find out that the "body is formatted as x-www-form-urlencoded", from the photo of body request in the browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255339/discussion-between-jurajc-and-teemu).

Comment: Actually I didn't, it was just a missinterpretation of the image. You've to check that the request headers are matching the format you're actually sending, and also make sure the server can support the format.

Comment: _"This is my code that creates that request"_ - that code creates the _data_ you are intending to send, but it doesn't make the actual request.